# react-native: Build Failed (in target 'react-native-orientation' from projects 'Pods')

Tags: javascript, react-native, cocoapods

I get build error image

[image: 1]

when doing npm run ios on my react native app but i removed that dependency from my podfile and did `pod install` and `pod update` but still gives me the same error

Comment: can you share your `package.json` file

Comment: i swear i remember npm uninstalling it but it was still there and now its gone ty @LouaySleman btw is there a explanation of that error or why it happens? am very new to cocoapods

Comment: it happens I will add an answer please accept it :D, To remove the package you need to check package.json if this happens again sometimes the package not removed correctly using npm uninstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check your `package.json` file and remove the package from it.

Comment: hello what if i dont want to remove it?

Comment: You need to find a replacement for the package.